# Issue with UserRepositoryImpl's missing 'update' method during UserPostUpdate event

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a Flutter project where I'm implementing user profile updates. However, I encountered an issue with the UserRepositoryImpl class, which seems to be missing the update method required for handling the UserPostUpdate event. I have provided the relevant code snippets below for reference.

```
// Code snippet 1: user_bloc and user_event

if (event is UserPostUpdate) {
  emit(UserPostLoading());
  try {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
      user = await userRepository.update(
        name: event.name,
        email: event.email,
        phoneNumber: event.phoneNumber,
        birthdate: event.birthdate,
        location: event.location,
        gender: event.gender,
        jobStatus: event.jobStatus,
        bio: event.bio,
        skills: event.skills,
      );

      emit(UserPostSuccess());
    });
  } catch (error) {
    emit(UserPostError(error.toString()));
  }
}

class UserPostUpdate extends UserEvent {
  // Event properties...

  UserPostUpdate(
    this.name, 
    this.email, 
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.birthdate, 
    this.location, 
    this.gender, 
    this.jobStatus,
    this.bio,
    this.skills,
  );
}
```

```
//code snippet 2: userRepository
class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
  // Other repository methods...

  Future<UserModel> update({
    String? name,
    String? email,
    String? phoneNumber,
    String? birthdate,
    String? location,
    String? gender,
    String? jobStatus,
    String? bio,
    List<String>? skills,
  }) async {
    String token = await getToken();
    print('start update');

    // Buat Map untuk menyimpan field-field yang diupdate
    Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {};

    if (name != null) {
      requestBody["name"] = name;
    }
    if (email != null) {
      requestBody["email"] = email;
    }
    if (phoneNumber != null) {
      requestBody["phone_number"] = phoneNumber;
    }
    if (birthdate != null) {
      requestBody["birthdate"] = birthdate;
    }
    if (location != null) {
      requestBody["location"] = location;
    }
    if (gender != null) {
      requestBody["gender"] = gender;
    }
    if (jobStatus != null) {
      requestBody["job_status"] = jobStatus;
    }
    if (bio != null) {
      requestBody["bio"] = bio;
    }
    if (skills != null) {
      String skillsString = skills.join(",");
      requestBody["skills"] = skillsString;
    }

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$baseUrl/users/update'),
        body: requestBody, headers: {"Authorization": token});
}
```

```
// Code snippet 3: EditProfilePage widget
class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfilePage();

  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {
  String message = "null";
  bool isChecked = false;
  String? selectedDate;
  List<UserModel>? user;
  List<String> userSkill = [];
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserModel loggedInUser =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as UserModel;

    TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController(text: loggedInUser.name);
    TextEditingController genderController = TextEditingController(text: loggedInUser.gender);
    TextEditingController jobStatusController = TextEditingController(text: loggedInUser.jobStatus);
    TextEditingController bioController = TextEditingController(text: loggedInUser.bio);
    TextEditingController locationController = TextEditingController(text: loggedInUser.location);
    TextEditingController phoneNumberController =
        TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController(text: '');
    // Access the properties of the logged-in user
    String? username = loggedInUser.username;
    String? email = loggedInUser.email;
    String? profilePhotoPath = loggedInUser.profilePhotoPath;

    handleUpdate(String message) {
      print("userSkill edit: $userSkill");
      print("message: $message");
      if (message != "null") {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(CustomSnackbar(
          color: Colors.red,
          icon: Icons.warning,
          message: message,
        ));
      }

      BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context).add(UserPostUpdate(
          nameController.text,
          emailController.text,
          phoneNumberController.text,
          selectedDate!,
          locationController.text,
          genderController.text,
          jobStatusController.text,
          bioController.text,
          userSkill));
      setState(() {
        message = "null";
      });
      print(message);
    }
```

**Problem**

The problem I'm facing is that when the UserPostUpdate event is triggered, it tries to call the update method of the UserRepositoryImpl class with the required parameters. However, I receive a NoSuchMethodError stating that the class has no instance method 'update' with matching arguments. I'm not sure why this error occurs, as the method seems to be defined correctly in the repository class.

**Error**

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'UserRepositoryImpl' has no instance method 'update' with matching arguments.
Receiver: Instance of 'UserRepositoryImpl'
Tried calling: update("john", "", "", "2003-6-30", "brazil", "male", "Student", "", Instance(length:5) of '_GrowableList')
Found: update({String? name, String? email, String? phoneNumber, String? birthdate, String? location, String? gender, String? jobStatus, String? bio, List<String>? skills}) => Future<UserModel>
```

---

I would appreciate any insights into why the update method of the UserRepositoryImpl class is not recognized during the UserPostUpdate event. If there are any alternative approaches or potential solutions to this issue, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error throw I think it can't find any match to update function's argument

I think probably is `Instance(length:5) of '_GrowableList'`

Do you have tried put empty list to see whether it pass or not?
Or in your repository have any other method name update?

References:
[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/NoSuchMethodError-class.html#:~:text=Error%20thrown%20on%20an%20invalid,checking%20prevents%20such%20invalid%20arguments](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/NoSuchMethodError-class.html#:%7E:text=Error%20thrown%20on%20an%20invalid,checking%20prevents%20such%20invalid%20arguments).